# JavaScript function changes object argument and all associated variables

Tags: javascript, object

Links: https://github.com/VirxEC/CalcPlus/blob/master/assets/Library.js and https://virxec.github.io/CalcPlus/PreviewLibrary/ these are just links to the main code if needed. The first link is the source, the second is the run environment.

The function expo has a very critical issue. I will explain what it does, then I will explain the exact issue and what I've tried to fix it. So the function is meant to calculate exponents up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1 digits long. (For the answer.) It works by running the multiplication function multiple times (on lines 196-197: `final = multi(num1, num1); for (var i="2"; isLessThan(i, num2); i=add({num:i.split(""),isNeg:false,decimals:0}, {num:["1"],isNeg:false,decimals:0})) final = multi(final, num1);`)

The objects that you see are passed into the `isLessThan()` function are examples of me passing pre-parsed numbers to the function doesn't have to re-parse them and take up computer resources. This passing of a pre-parsed object is where the error is. On line 197, you can see `final = multi(final, num1);` The `final` variable is not pre-parsed for obvious reasons, but num1 is. However, if you go into the chrome debugger and watch the `num1` variable, the `multi()` function changes the content of the property `num1.num` from (if you did 2<sup>64</sup>) from `["2"]` to `["0","2"]` causing and incorrect answer.

I've tested force-removing this behavior is intended for the `multi` function, but it shouldn't be modifying the argument. I've tried naming the variable something else, using const, and trying to set the object to be read-only nothing has worked. I've even tried something like this:

```
num1save = num1;
final = multi(num1, num1);
for (var i="2"; isLessThan(i, num2); i=add({num:i.split(""),isNeg:false,decimals:0}, {num:["1"],isNeg:false,decimals:0})) {
    final = multi(final, num1);
    num1 = num1save;
}
```

However, somehow, the variable manages to change num1save. Any variable referenced at some point to the object is changed. I have no idea why this is happening. This same thing happens with the `isLessThan()` function and the variable `num2` on line 197.

This includes only the required code, so the lines won't match up:

```js
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
// https://github.com/VirxEC/CalcPlus/blob/master/LICENSE
function parseNums(num1pre, num2pre, mode) {
  if (["string", "object"].indexOf(typeof num1pre) == -1) throw new TypeError("The first number wasn't a string (or object). It has to be a string (or object). Note that an object input is ment to submit a pre-parsed number.");
  if (["string", "object"].indexOf(typeof num2pre) == -1) throw new TypeError("The second number wasn't a string (or object). It has to be a string (or object). Note that an object input is ment to submit a pre-parsed number.");
  if (typeof mode != "number" || [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].indexOf(mode) == -1) throw new TypeError("The mode must be a number from 1-5.");
  var num1 = num1pre,
    num2 = num2pre,
    skip = false,
    stringMode1 = true,
    stringMode2 = true,
    neg = [false, false, false],
    decimal = 0,
    decimal1 = 0,
    decimal2 = 0,
    num1pos, num2pos, maxChar, numl;
  if (num1.num != undefined) neg[1] = num1pre.isNeg, decimal1 = num1pre.decimals, num1 = num1pre.num, stringMode1 = false;
  if (num2.num != undefined) neg[2] = num2pre.isNeg, decimal2 = num2pre.decimals, num2 = num2pre.num, stringMode2 = false;
  if (stringMode1 && num1.split("-").length == 2) num1 = num1.split("-")[1], neg[1] = true;
  if (stringMode2 && num2.split("-").length == 2) num2 = num2.split("-")[1], neg[2] = true;
  if (neg[1] != neg[2] && mode != 1 && mode != 2) neg[0] = true;
  if (stringMode1) num1 = num1.split('').filter(w => w != ",");
  if (stringMode2) num2 = num2.split('').filter(w => w != ",");
  num1pos = num1.indexOf("."), decimal1 = num1pos != -1 ? num1.filter(w => w != ".").length - num1pos : 0, num2pos = num2.indexOf("."), decimal2 = num2pos != -1 ? num2.filter(w => w != ".").length - num2pos : 0, decimal = mode == 1 || mode == 2 ? Math.max(decimal1, decimal2) : mode == 3 ? decimal1 + decimal2 : decimal1 - decimal2, maxChar = Math.max(num1.length, num2.length);
  for (var i = 0; !skip && num2.length == maxChar && i < num2.length && (((neg[1] || neg[2]) && mode == 1) || mode == 2); i++)
    if (+num2[i] > +num1[i]) neg[0] = true, skip = true;
  if (decimal < 0) decimal = 0;
  if (maxChar == num2.length && mode == 3) num1 = [num2, num2 = num1][0]
  if (decimal1 != decimal2 && [1, 2].indexOf(mode) > -1) {
    if (decimal1 == decimal)
      for (var i = 0; i < decimal1 - decimal2; i++) num2.push("0");
    else if (decimal2 == decimal)
      for (var i = 0; i < decimal2 - decimal1; i++) num1.push("0");
  }
  if (num1.length != num2.length && [1, 2].indexOf(mode) > -1) {
    numl = [num1.length, num2.length];
    if (maxChar == numl[0])
      for (var i = 0; i < numl[0] - numl[1]; i++) num2.unshift("0");
    else if (maxChar != num1[0])
      for (var i = 0; i < numl[1] - numl[0]; i++) num1.unshift("0");
  }
  if (mode == 3 && neg.every(e => (e == true))) neg[0] = false;
  return {
    num1: {
      num: num1,
      isNeg: neg[1],
      decimals: decimal1
    },
    num2: {
      num: num2,
      isNeg: neg[2],
      decimals: decimal2
    },
    isNeg: neg[0],
    maxChar: maxChar,
    decimals: decimal
  };
}

function formatNums(final, decimals, neg) {
  if (typeof final == "string") {
    if (decimals > 0) {
      final = final.split("");
      final.splice(final.length - decimals, 0, ".");
      final = final.join("");
    }
  } else if (typeof final == "object") {
    if (decimals > 0) {
      final = final.reverse();
      final.splice(final.length - decimals, 0, ".");
      final = final.join("");
    } else final = final.reverse().join("");
  }
  final = neg[0] ? "-" + final : final;
  final = ["", ".", "-"].indexOf(final) > -1 ? "0" : final;
  return final;
}

function add() {
  function tempadd(num1, num2) {
    var parsedNums = parseNums(num1, num2, 1),
      neg = [parsedNums.isNeg, parsedNums.num1.isNeg, parsedNums.num2.isNeg],
      maxChar = parsedNums.maxChar,
      decimal = [parsedNums.decimals, parsedNums.num1.decimals, parsedNums.num2.decimals],
      num1 = parsedNums.num1.num,
      num2 = parsedNums.num2.num,
      time, final = [],
      carry = "0",
      finali;
    if (neg[2]) return sub(parsedNums.num1, {
      num: num2,
      isNeg: false,
      decimals: decimal[1]
    });
    else if (neg[1]) return sub(parsedNums.num2, {
      num: num1,
      isNeg: false,
      decimals: decimal[2]
    });
    for (var i = maxChar - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      finali = maxChar - i - 1;
      if (time != i + 1) carry = "0";
      final[finali] = String(+num1[i] + (+num2[i]) + (+carry));
      if (+final[finali] > 9) {
        var temp = final[finali].split('');
        final[finali] = temp[1], carry = temp[0], time = i;
        if (i - 1 < 0) final.push(carry);
      }
    }
    return formatNums(final, decimal[0], neg);
  }
  var permfinal, a = arguments;
  if (Array.isArray(a[0])) a = a[0];
  permfinal = tempadd(a[0], a[1]);
  for (var i = 2; i < a.length; i++) permfinal = tempadd(permfinal, a[i]);
  return permfinal;
}

function sub() {
  function tempsub(num1pre, num2pre) {
    var parsedNums = parseNums(num1pre, num2pre, 2),
      neg = [parsedNums.isNeg, parsedNums.num1.isNeg, parsedNums.num2.isNeg],
      maxChar = parsedNums.maxChar,
      decimal = [parsedNums.decimals, parsedNums.num1.decimals, parsedNums.num2.decimals],
      num1 = parsedNums.num1.num,
      num2 = parsedNums.num2.num,
      final = [],
      finali, fans;
    if (neg[0] && !neg[1] && !neg[2]) num1 = [num2, num2 = num1][0];
    else if (neg[1] && neg[2]) num1 = [num2, num2 = num1][0];
    else if (neg[2] && !neg[1]) return add(parsedNums.num1, {
      num: num2,
      isNeg: false,
      decimals: decimal[2]
    });
    else if (neg[1] && !neg[2]) return "-" + add({
      num: num1,
      isNeg: false,
      decimals: decimal[1]
    }, parsedNums.num2);
    for (var i = maxChar - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
      finali = maxChar - i - 1, fans = num1[i] - num2[i];
      if (fans < 0 && i != 0) {
        var j = i - 1;
        final[finali] = String(fans + 10), num1[j] = String(num1[j] - 1);
        while (num1[j] < 0 && j != 0) num1[j] = String((+num1[j]) + 10), j = j - 1, num1[j] = String(num1[j] - 1);
      } else if (fans < 0 && i == 0) final[finali] = String(fans).split("-")[1];
      else final[finali] = fans;
    }
    return formatNums(final, decimal[0], neg);
  }
  var permfinal, a = arguments;
  if (Array.isArray(a[0])) a = a[0];
  permfinal = tempsub(a[0], a[1]);
  for (var i = 2; i < a.length; i++) permfinal = tempsub(permfinal, a[i]);
  return permfinal;
}

function isLessThan() {
  function templessthan(num1, num2) {
    var num = sub(num2, num1);
    if (num.split("-").length == 1 && num != 0) return true;
    return false;
  }
  var permfinal, a = arguments;
  if (Array.isArray(a[0])) a = a[0];
  permfinal = templessthan(a[0], a[1]);
  for (var i = 2; i < a.length; i++) permfinal = templessthan(permfinal, a[i]);
  return permfinal;
}

function multi() {
  function tempmulti(num1pre, num2pre) {
    var parsedNums = parseNums(num1pre, num2pre, 3),
      neg = [parsedNums.isNeg, parsedNums.num1.isNeg, parsedNums.num2.isNeg],
      final = "",
      decimals = parsedNums.decimals,
      numArray = [],
      num2 = parsedNums.num2,
      num1 = parsedNums.num1;
    if (num2.num.length == 1 && num2.num[0] == "1") return formatNums(num2.num, decimals, neg);
    else if (num2.length == 1 && num2[0] == "0") return "1";
    else {
      final = add(num1, num1);
      for (var i = "2"; isLessThan(i, num2); i = add({
          num: i.split(""),
          isNeg: false,
          decimals: 0
        }, {
          num: ["1"],
          isNeg: false,
          decimals: 0
        })) final = add(final, num1);
    }
    return formatNums(final, decimals, neg);
  }
  var permfinal, a = arguments;
  if (Array.isArray(a[0])) a = a[0];
  permfinal = tempmulti(a[0], a[1]);
  for (var i = 2; i < a.length; i++) permfinal = tempmulti(permfinal, a[i]);
  return permfinal;
}

function expo() {
  function tempexpo(num1pre, num2pre) {
    var parsedNums = parseNums(num1pre, num2pre, 5),
      num1 = parsedNums.num1,
      num2 = parsedNums.num2,
      decimals = parsedNums.decimals,
      decimal2 = parsedNums.num2.decimals,
      neg = [parsedNums.isNeg, parsedNums.num1.isNeg, parsedNums.num2.isNeg],
      numArray = [],
      final = "";
    if (neg[1]) num1.num.unshift("-");
    if (neg[2]) num2.num.unshift("-");
    if (decimal2 > 0) {
      // root_of_decimal2*10(num1)**(num2*(10*decimal2))
      alert("Decimal exponents aren't supported yet");
      throw new TypeError("Decimal exponents aren't supported yet");
    } else {
      if (num2.num.length == 1 && num2.num[0] == "1") return formatNums(num2.num, decimals, false);
      else if (num2.num.length == 1 && num2.num[0] == "0") return "1";
      else {
        final = multi(num1, num1);
        for (var i = "2"; isLessThan(i, num2); i = add({
            num: i.split(""),
            isNeg: false,
            decimals: 0
          }, {
            num: ["1"],
            isNeg: false,
            decimals: 0
          })) {
          final = multi(final, num1);
          console.log(num1, num2, i);
        }
        return final;
      }
      //Need to fix div -> if (neg[2]) return div("1", final);
    }
  }
  var permfinal, a = arguments;
  if (Array.isArray(a[0])) a = a[0];
  permfinal = tempexpo(a[0], a[1]);
  for (var i = 2; i < a.length; i++) permfinal = tempexpo(permfinal, a[i]);
  return permfinal;
}

console.log(expo("2", "64"));
```

*Why is this happening? Is there a work-around?*

*If you saw the previous post, sorry. I've been very frustrated with this bug.*

Comment: tl;dr please add in short, some inputs and the wanted outputs and what not work

Comment: Are you aware that objects are referential? E.g., `var one = {}; var two = one; two.text = "Hello world!"; console.log(one.text); //"Hello world"`. That's not rhetorical, I'm just making sure before digging through the post. Any time I see that an update to one variable is "updating another", that's the first question.

Comment: Since you have a lot of functions, that each does a lot of stuff, i would recommend writing some unit tests for each function. That way you will likely find the bug while writing the tests, and then you'll have the test to make sure that you don't introduce the same bug again in the future. (Also as a side note, i would recommend using the function signature syntax for arguments rather than extracting them from the global `arguments` variable.)

Comment: Here's a basic example showing how `var a = b` doesn't create a clone but merely another reference to the same object: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/9L62xygr/ (a quick solve is `var a = {...b}`, provided they are flat objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing the following:

```
var num1save = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(num1));
var num2save = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(num2));
```

sets a save variable that isn't just a reference but is instead a good copy and then doing this to set the save:

```
num1 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(num1save));
num2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(num2save));
```

doesn't prevent the problem from happening, but prevents it from causing any issues. Appling this in a way other than in the for loop would prevent the issue from happening.